# Adding item in combobox from text file

Tags: c++, winapi, combobox, ifstream

I'm new with C++ I can't seem to add a ComboBox item.
I always get the error that str can't be converted to lparam and I can't figure out another way.

Can someone please help me with this.
Thanks!

```
string line;
ifstream myfile ("test.txt");

    if (myfile.is_open()) {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) ) {

        //  SendMessage(hWndComboBox,(UINT) CB_ADDSTRING,(WPARAM) 0,(LPARAM) line); 
            cout << line << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
```

The line gets the error. Assigning the string to the lparam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CB_ADDSTRING` expects the `lParam` parameter to be a raw `TCHAR*` pointer to a C-style null-terminated character string (where `TCHAR` is `char` for ANSI, or `wchar_t` for Unicode, depending on whether the ComboBox is created with the `A`nsi or `W`ide version of `CreateWindow/Ex()`).

But you are trying to type-cast the `std::string` object itself, which will not work.  You need to type-cast a pointer to the string's data instead.

To get a null-terminated pointer to the string's character data, you need to use the string's `c_str()` method (or its `data()` method in C++11 and later), eg:

```
SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM) line.c_str());
```

Or, using a C++-style cast instead of a C-style cast:

```
SendMessage(hWndComboBox, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(line.c_str()));
```

Note, if the ComboBox is using Unicode, you can't send your `std::string` data as-is. You will have to rewrite your code to use `std::wstring` instead, or at least convert your `std::string` data to `std::wstring` (such as with `MultiByteToWideChar()` or `std::wstring_convert`) before passing it to `CB_ADDSTRING`.

Answer (score -2):

I may be able to help.  I can direct you to look at your:

```
 while( getline(myfile,line) ) {
```

The issue seems to be with using those two different types of variables. It also seems like you want your user to enter in data and take that whole line of data into a string variable. Try:

```
 while( getline(cin, line) ) {
```

does that work?

Comment: This answer DOESN'T attempt to address the issue actually being asked about - how to convert the `std::string` to `LPARAM`.